# EE Channels in Structure?

Tags: ee2, templates, structure, javascript

I'm running into an issue with displaying a marquee across pages on a site that has an index page and calendar page outside of Structure, while all other pages are within Structure.  The code I'm trying to run in the header is:

```
<div class="demo">   
 <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left" width="350">
  <p>  
   {exp:channel:entries channel="marquee" limit="3" status="open"}
     {marquee}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
  </p>
 </marquee>
<div>
```

It displays fine on /index and /calendar which are NOT the Structure pages. For every other page I can see the marquee loading however the content between the paragraph tags is blank such as:

The reason I'm wondering if this is an issue with how the templates are Structure is because when I try:

```
<div class="demo">
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left" width="350">
  <p>Hello, this is a test.</p> 
</marquee> 
</div>
```

The marquee loads as I would like it across all pages; Structure and Non-Structure.

To get around the HTML  tag I'm using Remy Sharp's Marquee jquery in the footer as such:

```
  $('div.demo').marquee('pointer').mouseover(function () {
  $(this).trigger('stop');
  }).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).trigger('start');
  }).mousemove(function (event) {
  if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
  this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
  }
  }).mousedown(function (event) {
  $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
  }).mouseup(function () {
  $(this).data('drag', false);
  });
```

as found on:
 http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/.

Any ideas of what I'm over looking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a dynamic="off" parameter to your channel entries tag - though I'm not sure how this will pan out with Structure.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="marquee" limit="3" status="open" dynamic="off"}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Totally groovy.  Overlooked that parameter :/